# How to get frame of SurfaceView each second?

Tags: android, android-camera, screenshot, surfaceview

I want to take screenshot from camera preview  each second.

I show preview of my Camera using SurfaceView. I need  to get preview each second(screenshot) but not using photo taking.

I know about method `mCamera.setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer` but I can take frame only one time from it. To make it updating every second I need to start `MediaRecorder` and record video. But For video I need to set `outputFile`, which means that it can use a lot of memory.

```
 mCamera.setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer(new Camera.PreviewCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
            int width = parameters.getPreviewSize().width;
            int height = parameters.getPreviewSize().height;

            YuvImage yuv = new YuvImage(data, parameters.getPreviewFormat(), width, height, null);

            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            yuv.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0, 0, width, height), 50, out);

            byte[] bytes = out.toByteArray();
            final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);

        }
    });
```

How can I do it without setting outputfile and taking photo each second?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `SurfaceView` to display your camera preview you may try calling `Camera#takePicture` every second.

To schedule it approximately every one second, you may use `postDelayed` method of any view. For example:

```
private Runnable capturePreview = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        camera.takePicture(null, null, callback);

        // Run again after approximately 1 second.
        surfaceView.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
}

private Camera.PictureCallback callback = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);

        // Do whatever you need with your bitmap. 

        // Consider freeing the memory afterwards.
        bitmap.recycle();
    }
}
```

And you can start it whenever preview is ready by calling:

```
surfaceView.postDelayed(capturePreview, 1000);
```

And stop whenever preview is no longer displayed:

```
surfaceView.removeCallbacks(capturePreview);
```

If you are using `TextureView` you can simply use `getBitmap()` which allows you to easily grab its current contents.

Therefore the code above becomes something like:

```
private Runnable capturePreview = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Bitmap preview = textureView.getBitmap();

        // Do whatever you need with the bitmap.

        // Run again after approximately 1 second.
        textureView.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
}, 1000);
```

And again start:

```
textureView.postDelayed(capturePreview, 1000);
```

and stop:

```
textureView.removeCallbacks(capturePreview);
```

Comment: getting this error: `java.lang.RuntimeException: takePicture failed
        at android.hardware.Camera.native_takePicture(Native Method)` in the line: `camera.takePicture(null, null, MainActivity.this);`